# How to display images from URL efficently

Tags: android, android-glide, android-image

I need to display a list of images in my application, and i get those images from an API call as an URL. Now I'm using `Glide` to show them, but i don't like the loading effect it makes (blank space while loading, and the the image). Is there any way to instant show those images, without any loading time and possibly without downloading them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the images are stored on a remote server there is no way to bypass the downloading process, however `Glide` makes sure to only download the image from remote server when necessary, as the docs state

> By default, Glide checks multiple layers of caches before starting a
> new request for an image:
>
> Active resources - Is this image displayed in another View right now?
> Memory cache - Was this image recently loaded and still in memory?
> Resource - Has this image been decoded, transformed, and written to
> the disk cache before? Data - Was the data this image was obtained
> from written to the disk cache before? The first two steps check to
> see if the resource is in memory and if so, return the image
> immediately. The second two steps check to see if the image is on disk
> and return quickly, but asynchronously.
>
> If all four steps fail to find the image, then Glide will go back to
> the original source to retrieve the data (the original File, Uri, Url
> etc).

To resolve this,

> but i don't like the loading effect it makes (blank space while
> loading, and the the image)

You can instead add a default placeholder on the `ImageView` until the real image is downloaded. This will display a default image while your actual image is downloading and then after download completion will replace it with the actual one.

```kotlin
Glide
.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder) //your default placeholder resource
.into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can display images from url by two ways:

- Without any third party library:

```html
    URL url = new URL("URL of image here");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

- Second way is by using [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)